# Why is the python logger in unit testing not working after setLevel called

Tags: python, logging, python-unittest

I have the following code in my `unittest` TestCase:

```
class StatsdLogHandler(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        log_entry = self.format(record)
        statsd_client.incr(log_entry)

def setup_statsd_logging(logger, level=logging.WARNING):
    # set up statsd counts for logging
    statsd_format = "pegasus.logger.%(levelname)s.%(name)s"
    formatter = logging.Formatter(statsd_format)
    statsd_handler = StatsdLogHandler()
    statsd_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    statsd_handler.setLevel(level)
    logger.addHandler(statsd_handler)

class TestLogging(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('.statsd_client')
    def test_logging_to_statsd(self, statsd_mock):
        """Make sure log calls go to statsd"""
        root_logger = logging.getLogger()
        setup_statsd_logging(root_logger)
        root_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        root_logger.warning('warning')
        statsd_mock.incr.assert_called_with('pegasus.logger.WARNING.root')
```

However, when I run the TestLogging test case, I get

> AssertionError: Expected call: incr(u'pegasus.logger.WARNING.root')
>
> Not called

I would expect this call to be successful. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

When I debugged this behavior, I found that `root_logger.manager.disable` was set to the value of `30`, meaning that all logging with a level of WARNING or lower was not being printed.

The logging `Manager` object isn't documented anywhere that I could easily find, but it is the object that describes and stores all the loggers, including the root logger. It is defined in code [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1017). What I found was that there were calls elsewhere in the test cases to `logging.disable(logging.WARNING)`. This sets the value of  `root_logger.manager.disable` to 30. The manager disable level trumps the effective level of the logger (see [this code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1371)).

By adding the line `logging.disable(logging.NOTSET)` to my test case at the beginning of the test case, I ensure that the logging manager `disable` property was set to the default value of 0, which caused my test cases to pass.